# gocron to add and remove task dynamically with parameter

Tags: go, cron

I am using `gocron` in my current project and I had encounter a few situations that not in the document.

I test this code:

```
gocron.Every(3).Seconds().Do(taskWithParams,2,"world")
gocron.Every(2).Seconds().Do(taskWithParams,1, "hello")
gocron.Start()

time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
gocron.Remove(taskWithParams)//<-- remove task
...

func taskWithParams(a int, b string) {
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

When I remove task(`gocron.Remove(taskWithParams)`), always `gocron.Every(3).Seconds().Do(taskWithParams,2,"world")` is removed. even I swap them:

```
gocron.Every(2).Seconds().Do(taskWithParams,1, "hello")
gocron.Every(3).Seconds().Do(taskWithParams,2,"world")
```

Is there a way for me to specifically point out which task I want to remove, since the `remove()` only allow 1 `argument`?

The document also have a `scheduler`:

```
s := gocron.NewScheduler()
    s.Every(3).Seconds().Do(task)
    <- s.Start()
```

1. When is the best use case for `scheduler`?
2. If we are done with scheduler, how to remove it from memory? do `scheduler.Clear()` does the job? or we have to have another way to clear them from the memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can handle the removal logic by deduplicating the function handlers.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fn1 := func() { taskWithParams(2, "world") }
    gocron.Every(3).Seconds().Do(fn1)
    fn2 := func() { taskWithParams(1, "hello") }
    gocron.Every(2).Seconds().Do(fn2)
    gocron.Start()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    gocron.Remove(fn2)
}
func taskWithParams(a int, b string) {
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Otherwise, the `scheduler.Do` method returns an instance of `*Job` that you can pass to `scheduler.RemoveByReference`.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    job, err := gocron.Every(3).Seconds().Do(taskWithParams, 2, "ww")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    gocron.Every(2).Seconds().Do(taskWithParams, 1, "hh")
    gocron.Start()

    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    gocron.RemoveByReference(job)
}
func taskWithParams(a int, b string) {
    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```